# Use variables in scope of a given function without passing

Tags: javascript, function, scope, local-variables

I want to use local variables like 'thisModule' in scope of the given 'functionToRun' without passing them as parameters.

```
Onsetsu.run = function (functionToRun) {
    var thisModule = Onsetsu.namespace(resolvedModule.moduleName);
    functionToRun();
};

Onsetsu.run(function() {
    /* thisModule should be visible here */
});
```

Unfortunately 'thisModule' is not defined in the scope.
Is there a convinient way to bring 'thisModule' into the functions scope?

Comment: The convenient way is to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Well, as said, passing them as parameters would not fulfill the requirements. Passing them as parameters would freeze the order the parameters are taken, which leads to a less modular and less maintainable way to access the given variables.

Comment: @Stefan - I'm confused.  The function isn't passed any parameters at all, so there is no order of parameters.

Comment: Which parameters are you talking about?

Comment: I was just decribing why I do not want to use parameters, so it's a "what if"-scenario.

Comment: Well, if you just pass one object and consider its properties as arguments (just like a lot of libraries do it, like jQuery's `.ajax`), then you don't have to worry about order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable in the closest shared scope of `functionToRun` and `Onsetsu.run`.  Assign the variable within `Onsetsu.run`:

```
var thisModule;
Onsetsu.run = function (functionToRun) {
    thisModule = Onsetsu.namespace(resolvedModule.moduleName);
    functionToRun();
};

Onsetsu.run(function() {
    /* thisModule should be visible here */
});
```

Assuming your actual code is more complicated than that:

```
(function(){
    var thisModule;
    var Onsetsu = (function(){
        var resolvedModule = { moduleName: "something" };
        return {
            run: function (functionToRun) {
                thisModule = Onsetsu.namespace(resolvedModule.moduleName);
                functionToRun();
            },
            namespace: function(moduleName){ ... }
        };
    })();
    Onsetsu.run(function() {
        /* thisModule should be visible here */
    });
})();
```

If `Onsetsu` is a library that you can't (or don't want to) modify, then you are out of luck.

**Edit:** You could also assign a property on the function itself:

```
Onsetsu.run = function (functionToRun) {
    var thisModule = Onsetsu.namespace(resolvedModule.moduleName);
    functionToRun.module = thisModule;
    functionToRun();
};
```

You can access the property from within `functionToRun` via `arguments.callee`:

```
Onsetsu.run(function() {
    var module = arguments.callee.module;
});
```

Or by giving the function a name:

```
Onsetsu.run(function fn() {
    var module = fn.module;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the to code fragments are even in separate files(a core library and asynchronous loaded modules, which are executed using the `Onsetsu.run` function).

Comment: @Stefan - Then the closest shared scope would be the global scope.  If you want to avoid namespace polution, expose it as a property of `Onsetsu`.  Or, use the other option I added to my answer just now.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach thisModule to the this reference inside functionToRun

```
Onsetsu.run = function (functionToRun) {
    var thisModule = Onsetsu.namespace(resolvedModule.moduleName);
    functionToRun.apply(thisModule,[]);
};
```

So inside your function you can refer to thisModule like so:

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log(this); // which will refer to thisModule
}
Onsetsu.run(myFunc);
```

Comment: The con is that you can only have one this. If you need other modules, you'll have to wrap them in an object.

Comment: @thunderflower that is correct, but it is also a good start, you can always use the second parameter of the apply method to pass other stuff

Comment: I already considered this as an option, but was not satisfied to use the this reference, because I wanted to apply the function later to different contexts while preserving the locals.

Comment: @StefanLehmann you are currently calling the function as an anonymous function, so this is refering to the window object.